# x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: mingw-w64

I am gettting this error 
"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory"
while building the MINGW64 on windows 7.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Can you add a simple sample program that causes this error and the build script you're using?

Comment: I am using scripts provided by the MinGW-builds project and the error is coming in libmangle build.

Answer (score 0):

I did setup mingw-w64 on win7/8 64bits but end up with different problems when compile different packages. And I found and follow a very clear and detailed instructions to setup  mingw-w64 w/ msys. Now it works well. You can have a look [here](http://ingar.satgnu.net/devenv/mingw32/base.html).

You can compile most of he packages at you own with cut-and-paste the instructions if you want to compile the listed pckage at your own.

Comment: I am trying to build the GCC with GCJ.